# MSSQL moved from WinSrv2012R2 to Linux - problem with swedish letters encoding

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding

We're in the process of migrating a sort of data warehouse database from SQL Server 2014 running on Windows Server 2012 R2 to a SQL Server 2019 that runs on Debian 10.

Migrating the database has gone pretty good, but we're facing an issue with conversion of Swedish language letters ÅÄÖ.

An example: On the old server "HYROR ÖRSTA" becomes "HYROR ÍRSTA" and on the new server it becomes "HYROR +RSTA".

I've changed the CI on the database to Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS just as it is on the Windows SQL Server.

Compability level has been set to SQL Server 2014 (120)

Here the changes can be seen:

[New Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dclSY.png)

[Old Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlJSb.png)

However this database is built by my economy controllers and have been a little bit free-style set up, and I am far from a DBA so we're at a loss how to fix this.

Any advice would be welcome :-)

Comment: Side note, Debian 10 isn't a supported operating system for SQL Server on Linux.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't change the characters, so some process you have is doing that, and clearly it is doing something differently on your new instance; show us the code you have that translates `'HYROR ÖRSTA'` to `'HYROR ÍRSTA'`.

Comment: Fully aware, don't care about supported operating system. Especially since Ubuntu is basically Debian anyhow. :) But thanks anyhow!


Yeah I just noticed that it's the new batch jobs ran nightly at our new server that converts wrongly. 

The "HYROR ÖRSTA" comes from DAT file that's encoded with iso-8859-1, when I cat that file, it says "HYROR RSTA", when viewed from windows it says "HYROR ÖRSTA"


I assume this is the problem, how would I best go around this? Convert the file before the batch job of SQL are ran, or convert inside SQL?

Comment: Converting in SQL is too late is the file is in the wrong code page; you need to do it when you read it.

Comment: *"Fully aware, don't care about supported operating system. "* you will do if you have problems with the instance as Microsoft won't support you. Although Ubuntu and Debian are similar, they are not the same. Just like Microsoft does not support installs on CentOS, even though is basically Red Hat.

Comment: "Converting in SQL is too late is the file is in the wrong code page; you need to do it when you read it. – "

OK I will add ISO-8859-1 locale and try, or worst case - convert files to UTF-8 before reading it. 

Thank you!

Comment: Converting the file to UTF-8 prior to running the batch-job in MSSQL to import the data has gotten somewhere. Ö has gone from "ÍRSTA" on Windows to "+úRSTA" instead. I am not sure how to proceed here, if there's an MSSQL setting or what to do?

Comment: Also, make sure the column collation, database collation, and instance collation are the same as the old instance before you import from a file with the correct encoding.